# HTTP 404 error. The requested resource is not available. I am using Jdk 1.8 and eclipse jee mars

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I am putting my code where I am facing problem.

WriteToPdf1.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.PDF;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.Page;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.Text;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.MoveTo;

public class ServletPDF1 extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename='CreatePDFFile.pdf'");

        PDF p = new PDF(out);
        Page p1 = new Page(p);
        p1.add(new MoveTo(p, 200, 700));
        p1.add(new Text(p, "Hi This is created PDF file by using Servlet"));
        p1.add(new Text(p, "by us...Bhumesh Patel...."));

        p.add(p1);
        p.setAuthor("Bhumesh Patel....");

        p.writePDF();
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<a href="/servlet1">CLICK HERE</a>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WriteToPdf1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletPdf1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ServletPdf1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletPdf1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please help I am doing this in eclipse jee mars and tried several options but could not execute it.I have attached all code. plz help.

Comment: Try with `<a href="~/servlet1">CLICK HERE</a>`

Comment: thanks hackerman.. tried but It din't work for me. plz suggest more

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the url mapping of a servlet in your web.xml file during runtime of the server, (depending on your server) it will not pick up on the changes. Try cleaning, rebuilding and restarting the server.

Comment: okay , what do you mean by rebuilding?

Comment: Each time you change something in your project, it usually builds automatically if your settings are set that way. If you're on Eclipse, click on the Project dropdown menu at the top of the window and you'll see "Build Automatically". Just restart your server and clean your project and you should see that the problem goes away.

Comment: okay,.. but It still is not working.

Comment: I found a new error in error log "Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git"

Comment: @Srana is your servlet in a package? Because maybe that's why it cannot be found. I normally keep my servlets in a package called 'servlets', so for the <servlet-class> tag in web.xml, i write:
 <servlet-class>servlets.ServletPdf1</servlet-class>

Comment: no, I have not put it this way. I'll jus try this way.

Comment: sorry.. it dint work. -

Comment: It is done..thanks all